# Resources for Arcpy Field Mappings String Syntax

Tags: arcpy, references, field-mapping

I need to edit an existing python script to add an additional field to a field mapping function. This field mapping function does NOT use the arcpy field mapping object--it instead uses a structured string such as:

```
PRINMERCD \"Principal Meridian Code\" true true false 2 Text 0 0 , First,#,{0},PLSSID_1,2,3;
        PRINMER \"Principal Meridian Text\" true true false 40 Text 0 0 , First,#,{0},PrincipalMeridian_1,-1,-1;
        TWNSHPNO \"Township Number\" true true false 3 Text 0 0 , First,#,{0},TownshipNumber_1,-1,-1;
        TWNSHPFRAC \"Township Fraction\" true true false 1 Text 0 0 , First,#,{0},TownshipFraction_1,-1,-1;
        TWNSHPDIR \"Township Direction\" true true false 1 Text 0 0 , First,#,{0},TownshipDirection_1,-1,-1;
```

I'm able to deduce much of what I see in here, but I really need documentation. So far, I haven't been able to locate any. ESRI keeps pointing to the field mappings object, which isn't much help since it isn't feasible for me to refactor tons of code.

This [article](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/08/30/field-mapping-and-python-scripting/) hints at my problem but then glazes over the string bit.

In summation, all I need is one document/resource explaining the syntax of this string so that I can manipulate it to suit my needs.

Comment: Much like the article says I would consider using FieldMappings object. The code would be more verbose but would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 7):

The string you are looking at is the string representation of the `field mapping` object which is used to map fields when exporting feature classes or when running operations that will combine attributes from multiple feature classes, for instance when running the `Spatial Join` geoprocessing tool when you may need to control the fields that will be taken into the output as well as their properties.

I am pretty sure you will not find any detailed docs on what each of strings part mean. I strongly suggest refactoring the Python code you have inherited though. Making changes using large strings will be a very painful process and you will benefit by introducing use of `field maps` and `field mappings` objects.

Anyways, here is the description (I have refactored a lot of legacy code myself, so I have done this deductive work a couple of years ago).

Here I load existing feature class fields into a new `FieldMappings` object and export it to the string. It's a great helper for debugging when you are not sure whether you have got your field mapping right.

```
>>> fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
>>> fms.addTable(r'Database Connections\dbo@esrigdb.sde\esrigdb.DBO.cities')
>>> fms.exportToString()
```

Each field is separated by the semicolon (`;`).

Let's take field `POP1990` to look at:

`;POP1990 "POP1990" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,Database Connections\\dbo@esrigdb.sde\\esrigdb.DBO.cities,POP1990,-1,-1;`

```
Name = POP1990 
Alias = "POP1990" 
Editable = true 
Is Nullable = true 
Required = false 
Length = 4 
Type = Long 
scale = 0
precision = 10
Merge rule = First
joinDelimiter = # (meaning '', null string)
Data source = Database Connections\\dbo@esrigdb.sde\\esrigdb.DBO.cities
Output field name = POP1990
-1
-1
```

I don't really know what `-1` and `-1` in the end stand for, but you happen to have `2,3` for the first field. If anyone knows what's that - please add a comment!

Hope this information will help you to refactor the code and use the field mappings object!

Comment: I was afraid of this answer, but nevertheless, thank you, Alex! I might be able to make use of the exportToString() method you've illustrated here for a quick/temporary fix. I too am baffled by the two numbers on the end. I'll repost here if I ever figure it out!

Comment: No problem! Working with legacy code can be a curse, good luck! :0

Comment: I've discovered since the original post that the two trailing numbers represent beginning/end characters of field value. Why -1, -1 is used to retrieve the full value, I don't know. However, if you insert other numbers, it works like an index slice. Just FYI in case anyone else has a similar question. Cheers!